# Text being cut off during localization

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, localization, dynamicresource

Okay, this is a really ridiculous problem for me because I had it working perfectly before. In my program I have `CheckBoxes` with text. The `Content` of these `CheckBoxes` are connected to `strings` located in Resource Dictionaries by `DynamicResource`.

My problem is that when the `Content` of these `CheckBoxes` changes, sometimes the text gets cut off, like so:

[image]

In the past, I believe this problem was solved by setting the `Width` property to `auto`. All of these `CheckBoxes` have their `Width` set to `auto`, but still get cut off. How do I make it so that the `Width` of the text is dynamic?

Note: This problem developed after I moved the `CheckBoxes`. They were working fine before.

EDIT: I've also tried removing `Width` all together, but I think that has the same effect as setting `Width` to `auto`.

Comment: They are most likely being cut off by another control, or by the container that they are in.  Please show your XAML.

Comment: I think it's being cut off by the container, I just need to figure out how to fix it. It's because I was accidentally placing it outside of my `Grid`. I'll give you the answer if you answer the question.

Comment: In order for us to help you, you have to let us know what you are using (i.e. post the XAML).  Otherwise, you are correct - "[*you*] just need to figure out how to fix it."  :)

Comment: Inspect the Visual Tree at runtime using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to better understand what's going on there.

Comment: @WonkotheSane I did fix it by making sure that the `CheckBoxes` are in the `Grid`

Comment: If they are inside a `StackPanel`, *that* could be your problem... if so, try putting them in a `Grid` instead. Maybe also try adding `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` on the `CheckBox`es if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

I found out through @WonkotheSane's comment that I was accidentally placing the `CheckBoxes` outside of the `Grid` that they were in when I moved them. To correct the problem all I had to do was make sure that the `CheckBoxes` remained in the `Grid`.